# Accessibility test being failed because text not included in an ARIA landmark

Tags: accessibility

I have some text which is spat out if JavaScript isn't turned on and this is currently failing an accessibility test.

It is within a `<noscript>` tag but the accessibility test is saying that the text is not included within a landmark.

None of the 8 standard roles seem to cover this, and I can see there is a generic role.

Is it therefore okay to use:

```
<noscript role="generic">
```

Or is that going to be a poor user experience for someone with a screenreader?

Thanks

---

Just fleshing this out a bit.

So actually when javascript is disabled via developer tools, the code just gets spat out on the with no tags at all.  Looks like:

```
<body>
 "Please ensure Javascript is enabled for purposes of.....
 <meta charset="UTF-8">............
```

The first landmark I can see is on the navigation so the message itself is not wrapped within another landmark.

It is being flagged an error because of:

- https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG22/Techniques/aria/ARIA11
- https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Techniques/aria/ARIA20
- https://alfa.siteimprove.com/rules/sia-r57

Based of the above, am I right in thinking I can either:

- Wrap the message in `<dialog>message to go here</dialog>` OR
- Bring the current message inside the `<header>` tag

Comment: It would be helpful if you could share the exact text being spat out and some more code. Does the message refer to any WCAG rules? Is it an error or a warning? Only about 60 % of accessibility issues can be tested automatically, often a manual verification is necessary. Probably like in this case. Is the text referring to the very noscript element? Is it inside another landmark?

Comment: I’m not aware of any specific rule on noscript contents, but the overall document needs to make sense. No matter if the landmark is declared outside or inside the noscript.

Comment: Hi Andy, thanks for your comments. I have fleshed out the original question now.

Comment: Sounds more like a testing tool false positive.  There isn't any requirement in WCAG that text must be in a landmark. Landmarks are certainly helpful, whether via semantic HTML such as `<main>` or `<header>`, or via ARIA attributes such as `role`, but you're allowed to have a webpage with no landmarks. I wouldn't recommend that but it's allowed.

Comment: > "Only about 60 % of accessibility issues can be tested automatically."  That's very generous of you, @Andy.  I typically say 20-30% of accessibility issues can be caught by a scanning tool. So much of WCAG is subjective that without AI, you can't really write rules to detect it. Higher percentages are typically quoted by makers of scanning tools, of course. Why would you want to advertise that your tool misses 70-80% of issues :-)

Comment: Could you post more code ? It's hard to say something with so few code. But generally there is no obligation to put any landmark anywhere. Anyway 99.99% of the world has js enabled so won't ever see the message.

Comment: @Johnny you shouldn’t need to do anything. As the Siteimprove reference states: “This rule is not required for conformance to any accessibility requirements.” Since it seems to be the only content of the page, no landmark is necessary. The code seems problematic, though: a `<meta>` element inside the `<body>` is highly irregular, if not an error. Maybe it confuses the Siteimprove tool? [According to ARIA in HTML you **must not overwrite the role of `<noscript>`**](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-aria/#el-noscript).